# Custom Nom parser error without custom ErrorKind

Tags: rust, parser-combinators, nom

I have a small parser that fails if the number it parses is out of bounds,

```
use nom::IResult;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::character::complete::digit1;
use nom::combinator::fail;

fn dup(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, u64> {
    let (s, _) = tag("dup")(s)?;
    let (s, n) = digit1(s)?;

    let n = match n {
        "0" => 0,
        "1" => 1,
        "2" => 2,
        _ => return fail(s), // FIXME: Annotate.
    };

    Ok((s, n))
}
```

*(See on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3052b12dbffb96591bf7ebc420007438).)*

But I'd like for the error to be more meaningful.

How do I annotate this error with the context that `n` is out of bounds?

E.g. instead of `fail()`, use something that provides an error message.

Or somehow wrap a part of the parser in something that provides this context.

I know that you can create your own [custom `ErrorKind`](https://github.com/baoyachi/rust-error-handle/blob/master/src/demo_nom_error_handle.rs), but can it be done without? (When you have an `ErrorKind`, [`error_position!()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.1/nom/macro.error_position.html) and [`error_node_position!()`](https://docs.rs/nom/7.1.1/nom/macro.error_node_position.html) macros will work.)

Comment: Someone asked if I can use `ErrorKind::Other` [like in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156146/parse-a-number-of-a-certain-size-in-nom); this is apparently not available in Nom 7. I've made the exampel compile and provided a link to the playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read [Error Management](https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/main/doc/error_management.md).

Broadly speaking, `nom::error::Error` is a low-overhead type for parser errors, that's why it only has *the parser's errors*.

If you want to attach more context, nom provides a `nom::error::VerboseError` type, there's also ancillary crates which provide  further error wrappers.

Finally, if that is *still* not sufficient nom's error handling is based around [the `ParseError` trait](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/error/trait.ParseError.html) so you can have a completely custom error type and implement *that*. The latter option obviously has the highest overhead, but also the highest level of flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Masklinn's answer (which I've marked as accepted), a way to add custom error messages without adding a custom error type is to use `VerboseError` and `convert_error()` instead of the default `Error`, since this is capable for embedding *context*. Here's a modified example (also on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=903e27839abffceb131314b1bc628fe7)):

```rust
use nom::IResult;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::character::complete::digit1;
use nom::combinator::fail;
use nom::error::{context, VerboseError};
use nom::error::convert_error;
use nom::Finish;

fn dup(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, u64, VerboseError<&str>> {
    let (s, _) = tag("dup")(s)?;
    let (sd, n) = digit1(s)?;

    let n = match n {
        "0" => 0,
        "1" => 1,
        "2" => 2,
        _ => return fail(s), // FIXME: Annotate.
    };

    Ok((sd, n))
}

fn main() {
    let input = "dup3";
    let result = context("dup", dup)(input).finish().err().unwrap();
    println!("{}", convert_error(input, result));
}
```

Adding `context("dup", dup)` provides a quite beautiful and readable context to the error message:

```
0: at line 1, in Fail:
dup3
   ^

1: at line 1, in dup:
dup3
^
```

but it does not add clarity at the innermost layer. If I add a context on the `fail` line:

```rust
let n = match n {
    "0" => 0,
    "1" => 1,
    "2" => 2,
    _ => return context("using an out-of-bounds dup", fail)(s),
};
```

then the message becomes

```
0: at line 1, in Fail:
dup3
   ^

1: at line 1, in using an out-of-bounds dup:
dup3
   ^

2: at line 1, in dup:
dup3
^
```

which is *almost* what I want! But I really just want to replace the message "in Fail" with "in using an out-of-bounds dup", not add to it. It is worth mentioning here what the Error Management docs say about `convert_error()`:

> Note that `VerboseError` and `convert_error` are meant as a starting point for language errors, but that they cannot cover all use cases. So a custom `convert_error` function should probably be written.

So the least complicated way I've found to add custom annotation/context to error messages, is using `VerboseError`, but also replacing `convert_error` with one that pops the `ErrorKind::Fail` and `ErrorKind::Eof` if they are followed by something with a context, in which case I expect the context to reside at the same position, causing a duplicate entry:

```rust
fn pretty_print_error(s: &str, mut e: VerboseError<&str>) -> String {
    let (_root_s, root_error) = e.errors[0].clone();
    if matches!(root_error, VerboseErrorKind::Nom(ErrorKind::Fail))
        || matches!(root_error, VerboseErrorKind::Nom(ErrorKind::Eof))
    {
        e.errors.remove(0);
    }
    convert_error(s, e)
}
```

Simpler solutions are welcome.